# Understanding a "matrix representation"

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider an abstract linear transformation; $$f: V \rightarrow V$$ $V$is a polynomial vector space of degree less than or equal to 2. Thus, it has a basis $1,x,x^2$. Now, what does it mean to say "find a matrix representation of $f$ in terms the basis $1, x, x^2$"?

How can an abstract vector space have a matrix representation? And how do we find it?

Comment: It's the map which has a matrix representation, not the vector space. The matrix should do to vectors what the map does to the vector, so you want $f(a1+bx+cx^2)=M_f(a,b,c)^T$ where $M_f$ is the matrix representation of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Every endomorphism $f: V \to V$ on a vector space $V$ of dimension $n$ can be represented using a $n \times n$ matrix $M_f$ such that

$$M_f v = f(v)$$

for all $v \in V$. $M_f$ is called the matrix representation of $f$ with respect to a particular basis.

**Example:** In your example, $V = \mathbb{R}[x]^{\leq 2}$ is the space of polynomials with real coefficients of degree $2$ or lower. A basis of this space would be $\{1,x,x^2\}$. Write $e_1 = 1, e_2 = x, e_3 = x^2$. Let $f: V \to V$ be given by $$f(v) = \frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx},$$

i.e. $f$ sends each polynomial to its derivative. This is clearly an endomorphism on $V$.

We can find its matrix representation by computing

$$f(e_1) = 0, \, f(e_2) = 1 = e_1, \; f(e_3) = 2x = 2 e_2.$$

Representing $e_1, e_2$ and $e_3$ in the usual way with vectors, i.e. $e_1 = (1,0,0)^T$ etc., we quickly see that

$$M_f = \begin{pmatrix} f(e_1) & f(e_2) &  f(e_3) \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 2\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

satisfies $M_f e_i = f(e_i)$ for $i = 1, 2,3$ as desired, and linearity guarantees that $f(v) = M_f v$ for any $v \in V$.

Answer (score 0):

Every finite dimensional vectorspace $V$ over a field $K$ is isomorphic to the vector space $K^n$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Why? In every finite dimensional vector space $V$ you can choose a (finite) basis $b_i$, $i=1,..,n$. Per definition every element $x$ in this vector space $V$ can be expanded in terms of this basis: $x=\sum_{i=1}^nc_i b_i$. The coefficients $c_i$ form a tupel $(c_1,...,c_n)$ which is an element of $K^n$.

With this in mind every linear map $f:V\to V$ can be regarded as a linear map on $K^n$. You can convince yourself that then a general linear map acting on a $n$-tupel is the same as a $n\times n$ matrix acting via matrix multiplication.
So for every particular linear map $f$ on $V$ there exists a corresponding matrix $M_f$. This matrix $M_f$ is called a "matrix representation" of $f$. Of course this representation depends on your choice of basis $b_i$.

One can construct the matrix $M_f$ from $f$ by writing the image of the basis vectors $b_i$ into the columns of the $n\times n$ matrix. Why? Consider the map $f$ acting on some vector $x\in V$:

$f(x)=f(\sum_{i=1}^n c_i b_i )=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i f(b_i)$

$f(x)=M_f\cdot \begin{pmatrix}c_{1}\\
\vdots\\
c_{n}
\end{pmatrix}=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i\begin{pmatrix}{(M_f)_{1i}}\\
\vdots\\
(M_f)_{ni}
\end{pmatrix}$

Comparing the two equations shows the claim.