# Linear map with polynomials - Find a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $F:P_3\to P_3$ be a linear map given by $F(p(x))=(x+1)p'(x)$ (where $p'(x)$ denotes the derivative).

(i) Specify the matrix $A$ for $F$ in the basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$

(ii) Determine a basis of eigenvectors to $F$ and the matrix $A'$ for $F$ in this basis.

---

I don't really understand what they are asking for in this exercise. I have seen a similar problem in an old exam. So I could perhaps just look at the solution for that problem and perhaps understand what they did to solve it. But that's not really how I learn. So my questions is, how do i find this matrix $A$? Why does it work and how can a basis be constructed of polynomials? Do you always use the same strategy to find $A$, no matter how the function is defined? Oh, and what do they mean by matrix $A'$? All i understand is what the function does and that the map is linear, so i have not come very far :)

Let $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ and so, the function maps this polynomial to $(1+x)\cdot p'(x)$. That is,
$F(p(x))=(x+1)(3ax^2+2bx+c)=c+(c+2b)x+(2b+3a)x^2+3ax^3=$$(0,c,c+2b,2b+3a,3a)\cdot (1,x,x^2,x^3)$. Well this is how far i've come since i don't understand the question... Hope someone can help me out. Thanks! :)

Comment: Do you know why $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ is a basis of $P_3$? The strategy you use to find $A$ is usually the same: You apply $F$ on your basis and then see which matrix $A$ satisfies $A \cdot v = F(v)$ for all $v$ in your vector space. The matrix corresponding to a linear map depends on a basis - thus if you take a different basis in ii), you will have a different matrix $A'$. My answer here might be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1087851/3787

Comment: No sorry. I can't really see why it is a basis of $ P_3$ :/

Comment: Do you see that $P_3$ is a vector space? Do you know what the definition of a basis of a vector space is? Can you write a general expression that every element in $P_3$ looks like?

Comment: I guess I see that $ P_3 $ is a vector space. The definition of a basis says that the vectors should be lineary independent and that every vector in the vector space is a linear combination of this set of vectors. When I think about a general expression of the elements in $ P_3$. I think about it in this way: $ a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$. Perhaps it's the wrong way to look at it?

Comment: That's correct. And what does a linear combination of the elements of the set $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ look like?

Comment: Sorry for my somehow slow responses. Trying to work out some exercises at the same time :) $\alpha_1 ( a, 0,0,0 ) + \ alpha_2 ( 0, bx, 0,0 ) + \ alpha_3 ( 0,0, cx^2,0 ) + \ alpha_4 ( 0,0,0, dx^3 )$ ? Is this right? Thank you for your help, it's not too easy for my brain to get this right now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column vectors of $A$ are the coordinates of $F(1), F(x), F(x^2), F(x^3)$ in the standard basis. As $F(1)=0$, $\;F(x)=x+1$, $\;F(x^2)=2x(x+1)$, $\;F(x^3)=3x^2(x+1)$, we find:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 
0&1&0&0\\
0&1&2&0\\
0&0&2&3\\
0&0&0&3
\end{bmatrix} $$
This is a triangular matrix, hence the eigen values are the diagonal elements: $0,1,2,3$. To determine the eigenvectors relative to these eigenvalues  you have to solve successively $\;Av=0$, $\;(A-I)v=0$, $\;(A-2I)v=0$, $\;(A-3I)v=0$.

In this new basis the matrix $A'$, by definition, will be the diagonal matrix $\;D(0,1,2,3)$.